# Determinar sequência de números com bubble sort de um arquivo txt em python?

Tags: python, array, lista, classificação, txt

Tenho um arquivo de entrada em txt com dados tipo os abaixo:

7  6  8

4  8  5

0  1  2

1  0  3

2  3  0

Esse arquivo se trata de informações de 3 alunos de uma escola. A primeira linha é a idade desses 3 alunos (a primeira coluna poderia ser aluno1, a segunda aluno2 e a terceira aluno3). A segunda linha é a nota das provas desses três alunos e da linha 3 até a 5 corresponde a uma matriz com a distância desses alunos em carteiras. (Por exemplo, na linha três: primeira coluna - a distancia do aluno1 para aluno1 é 0. Segunda coluna - a distância do aluno1 para aluno2 é 1 carteira. Terceira coluna - a distancia do aluno1 para aluno 2. A mesma ideia para as linhas 4 e 5.

Eu preciso de um código que utilize bubble sort para ordenar e que leia esse arquivo txt e ordene as informações de acordo com a menor para a maior idade dos alunos e que as outras linhas sigam essa ordenação.

Portanto, o programa deveria retornar:

6  7  8

8  4  5

0  1  3

1  0  2

3  2  0

Até o momento eu consegui fazer um código que ordenasse apenas a primeira linha, sem conexão com a segunda linha e a matriz. O código segue abaixo:

```
#lendo o arquivo com os dados no modo read.
arquivo = open('alunos.txt','r'); 

#lê uma linha do arquivo de texto
linha = arquivo.readline()

#Fecha o arquivo de texto
arquivo.close()

#Cria uma lista substituindo os espaços por virgulas
lista = linha.rsplit("  ")

#Determina o tamanho da lista para as condições do  bubble sort
tam_entrada = len(lista)

#Bubble Sort
for i in range (tam_entrada):
    for j in range (1, tam_entrada-i):
        if lista[j] < lista[j-1]:
            lista[j], lista[j-1] = lista[j-1], lista[j]

#Imprime a lista depois da utilização do bubble sort
print ("A ordem dos alunos classificados de acordo com a idade é: \n", lista)
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a completar o código ou talvez me ajudar com ideias novas?

Muito obrigado!

Comment: OBS: o arquivo txt não tem linhas em branco entre as linhas e as colunas são separadas por 2 espaços.

Comment: Mas a ordenação tem que ser especificamente com *bubble sort* ? Isto faz parte de algum exercício ?

Answer (score 2):

Antes de mais nada, vamos criar duas funções que para nos auxiliar.

A primeira função recebe uma linha do arquivo e devolve uma lista de inteiros.

```
def parse(linha):
    return [int(x) for x in linha.split()]
```

A segunda função faz o contrário, pega uma lista e devolve uma linha:

```
def emitir(valores):
    return ' '.join(map(str, valores))
```

Agora podemos começar com a lógica do programa.

Primeiramente, vamos ler as linhas do arquivo original:

```
with open('arquivo.txt') as f:
    linhas = f.readlines()
```

Feito isso, vamos separar a primeira e a segunda linha, cada uma em uma variável:

```
idades = parse(linhas[0])
notas = parse(linhas[1])
```

Aqui vem um truque. Vamos transpor os valores, assim criamos uma lista em que cada item é uma tupla com a idade do aluno, a sua nota e seu índice no arquivo original. Isso vai facilitar a ordenação.

```
alunos = zip(idades, notas, range(len(idades)))
```

Agora vamos ordenar os valores. Eu vou usar a função padrão do Python, tu pode criar uma com o o bubblesort se quiser (isso não vai fazer diferença). Depois de ordenar, temos que desfazer a transposição para facilitar a escrita do arquivo final.

```
alunos = sorted(alunos)
idades, notas, indices = zip(*alunos)
```

Chegou a vez de ler as distâncias entre cada aluno. Vamos criar uma dicionário que recebe o índice de dois alunos e devolve a distância entre eles. Perceba que a distância entre o aluno `i` e `j` é a mesma entre `j` e `i` (obviamente).

```
distancias = {}

for i, linha in enumerate(linhas[2:]):
    for j, distancia in enumerate(parse(linha)):
        distancias[i, j] = distancia
        distancias[j, i] = distancia
```

Todos os dados estão tratados, então temos que criar o output. Perceba que a matriz final é gerada a partir da distância original entre os alunos, mas na ordem em que eles aparecem após ordenados.

```
output = ''
output += emitir(idades) + '\n'
output += emitir(notas) + '\n'
output += '\n'.join(emitir(distancias[i, j] for j in indices) for i in indices)
```

O último passo é escrever o arquivo final:

```
with open('final.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(output)
```

A saída do arquivo é:

```
6 7 8
8 4 5
0 1 3
1 0 2
3 2 0
```

---

Eu tenho um desafio para ti:

Note que a matriz de distâncias é espelhada (a diagonal inferior é o espelho da diagonal superior). Atualmente a variável `matriz` salva todos os valores, inclusive os duplicados. É possível gerar o mesmo output sem duplicar nenhum valor?